# Number format in Google Chart Treemap Tooltip

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm creating a Treemap chart in Google Charts and after following some of the guides, I'm unable to get commas to display in the Tooltip. I've copied the JS below.

Essentially, I would like to have the number displayed in the tooltip to be in currency format with commas. But I can't seem to get the commas to show up.

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['treemap']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

var numberFormat = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
groupingSymbol: ','
   });
  numberFormat.format(data, 1);


  function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'ID');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Budget');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Amount');
  data.addRows([
    ['Program', null, 0],

    ['Housing', 'Program', null],
    ['Home1', 'Housing', 2000000],
    ['Home2', 'Housing', 1500000],


    ['Business', 'Program', 2000000],
    ['Coastal Resiliency', 'Program', 5000000],
            ['Infrastructure/City Services', 'Program', 400000],


  ]);

  var tree = new google.visualization.TreeMap(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  var options = {
    highlightOnMouseOver: true,
    maxDepth: 1,
    maxPostDepth: 2,
    minColor: '#FDC217',
    midColor: '#29BD75',
    maxColor: '#21809C',
    headerHeight: 35,
    headerColor: "#234E94",
    fontColor: "White",
    showScale: true,
    height: 500,
    useWeightedAverageForAggregation: true,
    generateTooltip: showFullTooltip
  };


    tree.draw(data, options);

function showFullTooltip(row, size) {
return '<div style="background:#FFFFFF; padding:10px; border-style:solid">' +
       '<span style="font-family:Times New Roman"><b>' + data.getValue(row, 0) +
       '</b>, ' + data.getValue(row, 1) +'</span><br>' +
   data.getColumnLabel(1) +
       ': $' + size + '</div>';

 }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm a bit new to this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `formatValue` method of `google.visualization.NumberFormat`

the method takes a number and return the formatted string

replace...

```
': $' + size + '</div>'
```

with...

```
': ' + numberFormat.formatValue(size) + '</div>';
```

also, if you format the `data` using `numberFormat`,
make sure it is *after* `data` is created...

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['treemap']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'ID');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Budget');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Amount');
  data.addRows([
    ['Program', null, 0],
    ['Housing', 'Program', null],
    ['Home1', 'Housing', 2000000],
    ['Home2', 'Housing', 1500000],
    ['Business', 'Program', 2000000],
    ['Coastal Resiliency', 'Program', 5000000],
    ['Infrastructure/City Services', 'Program', 400000]
  ]);

  var numberFormat = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    pattern: '#,##0',
    prefix: '$'
  });
  numberFormat.format(data, 2);

  var tree = new google.visualization.TreeMap(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  var options = {
    highlightOnMouseOver: true,
    maxDepth: 1,
    maxPostDepth: 2,
    minColor: '#FDC217',
    midColor: '#29BD75',
    maxColor: '#21809C',
    headerHeight: 35,
    headerColor: "#234E94",
    fontColor: "White",
    showScale: true,
    height: 500,
    useWeightedAverageForAggregation: true,
    generateTooltip: showFullTooltip
  };


  tree.draw(data, options);

  function showFullTooltip(row, size) {
    return '<div style="background:#FFFFFF; padding:10px; border-style:solid">' +
       '<span style="font-family:Times New Roman"><b>' + data.getValue(row, 0) +
       '</b>, ' + data.getValue(row, 1) +'</span><br>' +
       data.getColumnLabel(1) +
       ': ' + numberFormat.formatValue(size) + '</div>';

  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```